# python create a function of a system of equations for use with fsolve

Tags: python, function, scipy

Lets say that I want to solve a system of nonlinear equations that are created from an iterative expression, i.e. x[i]-2*x[i-2]...=1/x[i]**2.

In order to achieve that I want to use
fsolve from scipy package. So I have first to create a function f(x), i.e.

```
def func f(x, imax): 

    for i in range(imax):

      y = [ x[i]-2*x[i-2]...-1/x[i]**2, ] #this should be a matrix containing the  

                                          #equations in where all the equations are 

                                          # seperated with ',' 
return y
```

without knowing a priori imax. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what your question is. Why don't you know imax? Are you hoping to pass y to fsolve or is func the argument to fsolve? I don't believe that either will work, the argument to fsolve has to return a number. I think you will need to describe your problem in more detail in order to get useful advice.

Comment: "without knowing... imax" meaning that the number of equations to be solved are defined from imax which should be an argument. After define the function you use fsolve like this: scipy.optimize.fsolve( func, inGuess, args = ( imax ). So the argument to fsolve is a function containing the system of equations. My problem is how to create this function having the number of equations depended from imax. e.g. I want to write fsolve(func,args(10)), or fsolve(func,args(20)) etc

Comment: This is an example that works:>>> def func2(x):
        y = [x[0]*cos(x[1]) - 4, x[1]*x[0] - x[1] - 5]
        return y

>>> x0 = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func2, [1, 1])
>>> print x0
[ 6.5041,  0.9084]